# Chaning a value in a pandas DataFrame using the .loc method and = operator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with missing values that I am trying to fill in.
I have made another dataframe that contains the necessary data to fill the missing values. Both dataframes have `year` & `month` columns that I use to decide what value to fill in.
The dataframe with the missing values is called `full_arranged` and the dataframe with the values I wish to import to the former is called `median_values`.

To fill in the missing data, I wrote the following code:

```
for column in full_arranged.drop(['year','month','day', 'date'], axis = 1).columns:
    for year in range(2016,2019):
            for month in range(1,13):
                temp_val = median_values.loc[(median_values['year'] == year) & (median_values['month'] == month), column]
                full_arranged.loc[(full_arranged[column].isnull()) & (full_arranged['year'] == year) & (full_arranged['month'] == month), column] = temp_val
```

After I run this code, I check for missing values, but none of them have changed.
What am I missing?

I have also tried to do the same but with the pandas method `pd.fillna` and got the same results (the missing values are of type np.nan but I also tired to run the same code with `pd.fillna` and pd.nan and it did not work).

`full_arranged` looks likes this:

| year | month | value_1 | value_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 | 3 | Nan | 3.52 |

`median_values` looks like this:

| year | month | median_value_for_value_1 | median_value_for_value_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 | 3 | 5 | 4 |

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of both DFs?

Comment: SiP yes, I'll add and example of both DFs.
Y U but how will that replace the existing nan values? I need to replace them completely for ML training later.

Comment: @Yuvalllllll, I meant a short code that produces the DFs so we can test it

Comment: Did you consider using ```newdf=full_arranged.merge(median_values, left_on=column_y_m_d, right_on=column_y_m_d,...``` where column_y_m_d is new column combining year, month, etc for join purposes.  After that you can use ```full_arranged.update(newdf,...)``` to fill na values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minimal example of both DFs would be helpful.

However, the condition `& (median_values[column] == column)` seems strange.

Don't you want to do something like this?:

```
= median_values.loc[(median_values['year'] == year) & (median_values['month'] == month),column]
```

So select the row by year and month and return the value of the column of the median_values dataframe?

**Update:**

More efficient would be the Pandas way:

```
    #Build Dummy Dataframes
    full_arranged = pd.DataFrame([[2017,3,np.NAN,3.52],[2017,3,4.5,9],[2017,4,4.5,np.NAN]], columns = ['year','month','value_1','value_2'])
    median_values = pd.DataFrame([[2017,3,5,4],[2017,4,6,7]], columns = ['year','month','value_1','value_2'])
    
    #Set Year/Month Index
    full_arranged.index = pd.to_datetime((full_arranged['year'].astype(str) + "-" + full_arranged['month'].astype(str)))
    median_values.index = pd.to_datetime((median_values['year'].astype(str) + "-" + median_values['month'].astype(str)))
    
    #Update NA Values
    full_arranged = full_arranged.update(median_values, overwrite=False)
```

pd.to_datetime is optional.

Comment: hey I have uploaded an example of the tables, let me know if that's ok.
I have corrected the code as you suggested but I still get the same results - for some reason I cannot change the original df - I only get a slice which does not affect the original df

Comment: Are "value_1" and "median_value_for_value_1" the real column names? They are probably identicaly in both dataframes, right? So both "value_1" or so?

Comment: exactly, the name I gave here for ease of understanding the idea.
but the names are the same

Comment: What do you mean by" I only get a slice which does not affect the original df"? I just tried your code with your dummy dataframe and the changes are properly made in the full_arranged dataframe.

Comment: And you seldom need for-loops in pandas. I added a more efficient way to my answer.